# Htaccess /imagename/delete

Tags: .htaccess, get

Okay so i'm working on creating a thing to delete images from my server. I figured out about the unlink function and have turned it into a get variable. How can I use htaccess to delete a file from my server with a url like this example.com/imagename/delete

```
RewriteRule ^/delete/([^/]+)$ index.php?delete=$1
```

I realized that this does /delete/imagename but I want the urls to be /imagename/delete. I tried the following but that didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$/delete index.php?delete=$1
```

I know this sounds simple and easy to find on the web but I can't seem to find this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rules to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/delete/?$ index.php?delete=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]
```

Comment: I think that maybe my existing htaccess file is interfering with that. I have this right now and get a 404 error  RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/delete/?$ index.php?delete=$1

Comment: Change their order. Add `[L]` to both.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/delete/?$ index.php?delete=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]

still not working

Comment: Add a `RewriteCond` to second rule.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/delete/?$ index.php?delete=$1 [L] 
RewriteCond ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]  gives me an internal server error

Comment: Are you placing these rules in htaccess or httpd.conf file? Where's the file located at.. root `/` directory? If it's htaccess then your first existing delete rule could not have been working since it starts with a `/` and it wouldn't have matched.

Comment: htacces. and I'm placing it at the directory where all the files for my subdomain go.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/([^/]+)$ index.php?delete=$1
is working fine

Comment: Please, remove the leading `/` and try again.

Comment: like this? If so I still get an error RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/delete/?$ index.php?delete=$1 [L] 
RewriteCond ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.png [L]

Comment: You have used RewriteCond in place of RewriteRule. Verify your code with my answer again.